# Начал изучать Js и возник один вопрос по поводу функций

Tags: javascript, html5

```
  let a=0;
    function timer(){
        a++;
        console.log(a)
    }
    timer()
    timer()
    timer()
```

Почему при вызове функции 3 раза, 3 раза в консоле будут выводиться разные значения . Я думал что функция timer каждый раз берет из своего окружения значение 0.

Comment: Если бы внутри функции была бы объявлена переменная с именем "а" - да, то была бы своя всегда

Comment: то есть допустим при первом вызове timer() на консоле будет цифра 1 так как в функции "а"=1 и на первой строке(вне функции) "a" уже имеет значение не 0 а 1.при втором вызове уже "а" в консоле 2 и соответственно мы переписали "a" и на первой строке тоже 2 и тд верно?

Comment: Почитайте про область видимости переменных, вам многое станет понятно )

Comment: да, если можно дайте ссылку

Comment: Yandex.ru -> Область видимости переменных javascript ->  и читайте )

Answer (score 2):

Переменная a объявлена за пределами функции, поэтому после каждого вызова функции переменная увеличивается. То есть при каждом вызове операция происходит с одной и той же переменной.

Для того, чтобы фукнция выводила всегда 1, то нужно объявить переменную внутри функции:

```js
function timer() {
  let a = 0;
  a++;
  console.log(a)
}

timer() // => 1
timer() // => 1
timer() // => 1
```

Comment: что то я всегда считал что глобальную переменную которая здесь "a" не можно изменить. а оказывается при каждом вызове функция перетирает значение которое на первой строчке, let a=0 но при вызове функций переписывается на 1 потом 2 потом 3. верно я понял?

Comment: @jonathanrogers Поэтому и рекомендуют использовать глобальные переменные в исключительных случаях. Значение глобальной переменной может быть изменено в любой функции, а это значит, что в случае возникновении ошибки, ее будет гораздо сложнее обнаружить.

Comment: большое спасибо) а то долго туплю что то, просто как то пропустил момент когда на уроках говорили о изменении глобал. переменной из функции)